# Replace MySql databases with a more recent copy via command line

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, backup-restoration

Ubuntu Server running MySql server.

We have 5 databases on our server.  On a recent crash, the server was restored incorrectly and now 1 database (B) has 2 incorrect tables and a 2nd database (A) is  completely incorrect.

How do I correctly replace database files?

Is it as simple as

```
cp -a /path/to/backup/databaseA/ /var/lib/mysql/databaseA
cp -a /path/to/backup/databaseB/table1.MYD /var/lib/mysql/databaseB
cp -a /path/to/backup/databaseB/table1.MYI /var/lib/mysql/databaseB
cp -a /path/to/backup/databaseB/table2.ibd /var/lib/mysql/databaseB
```

And for what it is worth, there are mixed MyISAM and InnoDB tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MyISAM - no problem (except metadata), regarding InnoDB: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15531/why-does-innodb-store-all-databases-in-one-file

I think your problem is in `innodb_file_per_table` - was this option enabled before tables were **created** on both A & B or not.

If `innodb_file_per_table` was enabled later - you will have mixed tablespace: some data will be saved in `.ibd` and some in `ibdata1`, metadata always stays in `ibdata1`.

Also, remember that not only database files provide information regarding tables and permissions etc (metadata) - `mysql` DB information tables and `ibdata1` do. So, copying is useful only when there is no change or you don't care about that metadata.

Short answer - no (you need `ibdata1` too). it's not that easy, but in some circumstances it might work anyway.

If this isn't answer you are looking for - this information might be very useful for you anyway.

Recovery: you need `ibdata1` too, but it will affect other DB's with innodb too.

Comment: Upon checking all Innodb tables are ok.  For MyISAM, can a mysql stop followed by copying MYD & MYI files work?  Are there other considerations?

Comment: If you stop mysql, then copy files and then start again - it will work.